# Use input from a file for a command

Tags: bash

I want to use the MAC address stored in a file in `aireplay-ng` command. I want this command to be executed once with each mac address in the file.

Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like `xargs -a FILE -d '\n' -L 1 -r COMMAND`.  `-a` and `-d` tell `xargs` to read the command line arguments from a file, one argument per line; and `-L1 -r` tell it to call the command once per input line, not running it if there's no input.

Answer (score 0):

With pure Bash, you should use a `while read` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r mac; do COMMAND "$mac" ; done < /path/to/file
```

Here, `$mac` will hold each line. The `IFS=` is a safeguard for leading and trailing whitespace.

See also: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) – it's not meant for reading from files.